# Wxpython wx.media Video & image control There are questions

Tags: python, wxpython

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx, wx.media
import sqlite3
import os
import time

class MainFream(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.leftPanel = wx.Panel(self, size=(0,0))
        self.media = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self,
                                        #szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_GSTREAMER,
                                        szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10,
                                        size=(0,0),
                                        style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        #Penael Sizer
        self.hBoxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.hBoxSizer.Add(self.leftPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND, 1)
        self.hBoxSizer.Add(self.media, 1, wx.EXPAND, 1)
        self.SetSizer(self.hBoxSizer)


        #Video Image File Folder Serach & Load Play
        self.mediaCounter = 0
        self.folderSerach = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(('.wmv','mp4','avi','.jpg'))]
        self.media.Load(self.folderSerach[self.mediaCounter])
        self.media.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.mediaPlay, self.media)
        self.media.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.mediaLoop, self.media)


    def auto(self):
        self.TextShow()
        wx.CallLater(1000, self.auto) #60min

    def mediaPlay(self, event):
        self.folderSerach = [x for f in os.listdir() for x in os.path.splitext(f) if x.endswith(('.wmv','mp4','avi','.jpg'))]
        for i in self.folderSerach:
            if i == '.jpg':
                self.media.Play()
                time.sleep(10)
                print('test1')
            else:
                self.media.Play()
                print('test2')

    def mediaLoop(self, evnet):
        self.media.Stop()
        self.mediaCounter += 1
        if self.mediaCounter > len(self.folderSerach) -1: self.mediaCounter = 0
        self.folderSerach = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(('.wmv','mp4','avi','.jpg'))]
        self.media.Load(self.folderSerach[self.mediaCounter])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    fream = MainFream()
    fream.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am creating a panel to search and play jpg, avi, mp4, etc. in folders.

In the `def mediaPlay()` section, jpg makes the picture file visible for 10 seconds, and the movie is played until the end of the playing time.

The question is, `if = '.jpg'`, only one `print ('test1')` statement needs to be executed, and 'test2' will be displayed at the same time. So `time.sleep()` is applied to the `if or else` statement. Why is this?

Comment: What's a Peneal Sizer and where can I get one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function you are overwriting `self.folderSerach` with a list of file suffixes.

```
def mediaPlay(self, event):
    self.folderSerach = [x for f in os.listdir() for x in os.path.splitext(f) if x.endswith(('.wmv','mp4','avi','.jpg'))]
    for i in self.folderSerach:
        if i == '.jpg':
            self.media.Play()
            time.sleep(10)
            print('test1')
        else:
            self.media.Play()
            print('test2')
```

replace it with:

```
def mediaPlay(self, event):
    if self.folderSerach[self.mediaCounter].endswith('.jpg'):
        self.media.Play()
        time.sleep(10)
        print('test1')
    else:
        self.media.Play()
        print('test2')
```

This overwriting of `self.folderSerach` means that you are having to re-load it again in `def medialoop` (remove that code)

Also, `os.listdir()` (at least on Linux) requires an argument i.e. `os.listdir('./')`
And, remove the `def auto` function it is not used

Comment: Thank you very much. The question has been resolved. I learned so much about you. :)

Comment: Hello I have another question.

It is good to stop the image with a short `time.sleep`. Thank you again for your teaching.

If you give Linux a long time.sleep, the process may hang or the frame screen turns black. In this case, do you need to configure the Linux system? Or is it a system performance issue?

Is there another function that stops the image for a desired amount of time other than `time.sleep`?

I also want to know if the whole frame flicker is normal in the process of going to Image -> Video -> ..-> like this by turning the branch code.